# X scale of ggpredict (package ggeffects) seems wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am struggling with correctly plotting my data by making use of the ggpredicts package.

When doing the same with ggplot2 everything looks correct, datapoints are correctly plotted.
But when using ggpredicts it seems that I have negative values in my dataset but that's 100% sure not the case.
The regression lines however are correct.

I prefer using ggpredict since I used it for all my graphs in my thesis so the lay-out matches, nicely.

Remarkably, it was correct for all the graphs except this one is acting strange.

An alternative could be matching the lay out from ggeffects in ggplot2 but I don't know how I could do that efficiently.

This code is from the ggplot2 package:

```r
ggplot(subset(KMIdata, !is.na(Temperature_cat)), aes(x=Traject100m, 
    y=ForagingSpeed, group=interaction(Temperature_cat), 
    col=Temperature_cat)) + geom_point() + 
    guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Temperature (°C)")) + 
    geom_abline(intercept=3.3446, slope=-3.5265, linewidth=1.2, 
                color='#F564E3') +
    geom_abline(intercept=3.986, slope=-7.3895, linewidth=1.2, 
                color='darkorange2') +
    geom_abline(intercept=3.9931, slope=-7.0185, linewidth=1.2, 
                color='gold') +
    geom_abline(intercept=4.365, slope=-6.3697, linewidth=1.2, 
                color='seagreen3') +
    geom_abline(intercept=3.457, slope=-2.5486, linewidth=1.2, 
                color='dodgerblue2') +
    geom_abline(intercept=3.7289, slope=-3.5265, linewidth=1.2, 
    color='dodgerblue4') + 
    ggtitle("Local urbanisation effect per temperature category") +    
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=15), 
          axis.title=element_text(size=13), 
          axis.text=element_text(size=13)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(name="Local urbanisation", limits=c(0, 0.58, 0.1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="Foraging speed (m/s)", limits=c(0,7,5)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=
          c("#F564E3", "darkorange2", "gold", "seagreen3", "dodgerblue2", 
            "dodgerblue4" ))
```

[image]

This code is from `ggeffects` package

```r
ggpredict(model_urb1, c("Traject100m", "Temperature_cat")) %>% 
  plot(add.data=TRUE) + scale_x_continuous(name="Urbanisation") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Foraging speed   (m/s)") + 
  labs(colour="Temperature (°C)", 
       title="Wind speed effect per wind direction") +  
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#F564E3","darkorange2","gold","seagreen3", 
                              "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue4" ))
```

[image]

I hope it is possible to help without needing the dataset.